# How am I bogging down on an attempted JavaScript include?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, optimization, infinite-loop

The simplified form of what I have is as follows:

An HTML page runs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Before scripts</p>
        <script src="/javascripts/json2.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/clock-skeleton.js"></script>
        <p>After scripts.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

clock-skeleton.js reads:

```
console.log('Starting clock.js.');
console.log('Finished pass through clock.js.');
```

The page seems to hang indefinitely. I don't see the "Before scripts" or "After scripts." Chrome's console does not seem to display the two log calls from the eviscerated clock.js.

Is there any problem with my including json2.js (from Douglas Crockford's Github offering) and jQuery.js (v3.2.0)?

What could I be doing to get it to bog like a JavaScript infinite loop?

**--UPDATE--**

I got sane behavior from my minimum case; I tried to add back [the original clock.js with copious logging behavior added, including the first line.](https://pastebin.com/WRSdV8t1) The minimum page is now acting like it has an infinite loop; Chrome is displaying a chopping version of what it lists when loading a page, and absolutely nothing is displaying in the log. (This behavior is consistent between when I load clock-skeleton.js as quoted above, and when I load [the real thing](https://pastebin.com/WRSdV8t1) plus debugging for the first line and almost every block.

I'm a bit concerned that I'm not managing to get one single line of console.logged information for either the minimum case quoted above or the full attempt at a wroking solution.

Comment: Is that all of the code in `clock-skeleton.js`? Does chrome's network tab show the files downloading?

Comment: That is all the code I pared down to `clock-skeleton.js` to present a minimal example. Chrome's network tab shows everything I want downloading.

Comment: Add a `debugger` statement at the beginning on `clock-skeleton.js` and see if chrome picks it up (dev tools must be open)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you closing your `<head>` tag. Also, it's generally not a good practice to mix your scripts in like this in the middle of the body, you'd want to include libraries like jQuery in the `<head>` but I'm assuming you're just doing it for testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry; the missing `</head>` was part of my effort to produce as simple a test case as possible. I usually put JavaScript at the end of the page rather than in the HEAD; have Yslow recommendations been subsequently revised?

Comment: No, javascript should go right before the closing `</body>` tag